# "admin.google.com is for G Suite accounts only", but no account set up yet

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I'm trying to set up G Suite for a church using Google for Nonprofits.  We've successfully applied for Google for Nonprofits, but when I try to `Get started with the Admin console`, I go to a page that says:

> admin.google.com is for G Suite accounts only. Regular Gmail accounts cannot be used to sign in to admin.google.com.`

The issue is, there are no accounts set up with our `example.com` domain name.  We set up Google for Nonprofits with a regular Gmail address, and the email confirmation we received listed this Gmail address as the administrator.  Whenever I try to use this account to sign in, though, I get the same message.

What account do I need to use to log in to the G Suite admin console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out somehow the church's domain name already got set up with Google, so we just had to [contact Google](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6335621?visit_id=0-636435812885656803-3106167105&rd=1) (sign up for G Suite and click the 'Contact us' link in the top right) and they were able to resolve the issue.